# MVC2 Problem refreshing View after Post action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Basically all I am trying to do is have a View post back to it's own post action method. I want the action method to update a simple value and have the view then display the new value. Below is some code snippets. The post action method receives the value from the textbox well enough but after updating this value the view does not display the new value:

**View:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="user_form" style="width: 600px; margin-top: 50px">
        <div class="user_form_header">
            Default Distribution List
        </div>        
        <% using (Html.BeginForm())
        { %>
            <div>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.CurrentPageIndex) %>
                <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Send" />
            </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DefaultDistributionListViewModel model = new DefaultDistributionListViewModel();
    model.CurrentPageIndex = 1;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DefaultDistributionListViewModel model, string submitButton)
{
    // repopulate the model
    model.CurrentPageIndex = model.CurrentPageIndex + 1;
    return View(model);
}
```

Controller:

```
public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HttpPost method, after you update the model.CurrentPageIndex and return View, Its gonna fire you HttpGet method where you reassign it.

```
model.CurrentPageIndex = 1;
```

Perhaps pass in a default parameter in your "Get" request.

// This sets a 'default' value as of c# 3 I believe
// If not theres a [Default] attribute you can use as well as int? page

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
{
    var model = new DefaultDistributionListViewModel {
        CurrentPageIndex = page
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DefaultDistributionListViewModel model, string submitButton)
{
    // repopulate the model
    model.CurrentPageIndex = model.CurrentPageIndex + 1;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new {page = model.CurrentPageIndex} );
}
```

Comment: thanks but when I tried this the updated value is not being passed into the HttpGet method. So no luck

Comment: That code will call the HttpGet version again because you are using "return RedirectToAction(...". If you use "return View(..." it won't call the HttpGet again. This is more of a workaround.

Comment: You might be right however, I used his code and set breakpoints to see the events that were getting fired.  On the post to the `Index()` method it would subsequently fire the Get method where it would obviously re-asssign the property as he had it hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like output caching is getting in the way. I would set up a cache profile and set it to not cache the view.

Here's how I do it.

Add to your web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="CacheProfile" duration="60" varyByParam="*" />
          <add name="ZeroCacheProfile" duration="0" varyByParam="*" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
  </system.web>
```

Add the attribute to your controller:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ZeroCacheProfile")]
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1) 
{ 
    var model = new DefaultDistributionListViewModel { 
        CurrentPageIndex = page 
    }; 
    return View(model); 
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Rick